# ELSE IF condition in PL SQL not working

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing a `ELSE IF` condition but it is not working.

```
IF P_TYPE='College' THEN      
  INSERT INTO SAPID_INPUTDATA_WIFI(BOCID,BUILDING_RJID,LOCATION_TYPE,TYPE)VALUES
  (P_BOCID,P_BUILDINGRJID,P_LOCATIONTYPE,P_TYPE) RETURNING ID INTO P_FLAG; 
  END IF;

ELSE IF P_TYPE='Public WiFi'  AND  P_LOCATIONTYPE ='Node BLDG'   THEN

  INSERT INTO 
  SAPID_INPUTDATA_WIFI(BUILDING_RJID,LOCATION_TYPE,TYPE)VALUES(P_BOCID,
  P_BUILDINGRJID,P_LOCATIONTYPE,P_TYPE) RETURNING ID INTO P_FLAG; 

END IF;
```

Comment: it´s called `elsif` in pl/sql.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy: tried with that too but still not working

Comment: then there´s some difference for `P_TYPE` or `P_LOCATIONTYPE` to the values you compare with, but without the correct syntax as `elsif` this shouldn´t have compiled/ worked to begin with. What´s not working here?

Comment: The whole syntax is broken even so i feel. Something is completly off here. It reads as `IF ... END IF; ELSE IF END IF`, where it should read as `IF ... ELSIF ... END IF;`

Comment: Please define 'not working'.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is syntax. Try this:

```
IF P_TYPE='College' THEN      
  INSERT INTO SAPID_INPUTDATA_WIFI(
    BOCID,
    BUILDING_RJID,
    LOCATION_TYPE,
    TYPE)
  VALUES(
    P_BOCID,
    P_BUILDINGRJID,
    P_LOCATIONTYPE,
    P_TYPE)
  RETURNING ID INTO P_FLAG; 

ELSIF P_TYPE='Public WiFi' AND P_LOCATIONTYPE ='Node BLDG' THEN
  INSERT INTO SAPID_INPUTDATA_WIFI(
    BUILDING_RJID,
    LOCATION_TYPE,
    TYPE)
  VALUES(
    P_BOCID,
    P_BUILDINGRJID,
    P_LOCATIONTYPE,
    P_TYPE) 
   RETURNING ID INTO P_FLAG; 

END IF;
```